# Extract only first occurrence of strings from each line

Tags: regex, csv, text, notepad++

I have a CSV file, around 5k lines, with the following example:

```
apple,tea,salt,fish
apple,oranges,ketchup
...
salad,oreo,lemon
salad,soda,water
```

I need to extract only first line matching apple or salad and skip other lines where those words occur.

I can do something like this with regex, "apple|salad", but it will extract all the lines where those words are found.

The desired result is:

```
apple,tea,salt,fish
salad,oreo,lemon
```

I'm able to use REGEX in a text editor and OpenOffice Calc application.

Comment: Do you have any experience of programming language such as `awk` or `python`,
or at least are you willing to learn?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I might be able to do grep or awk via Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: Okay, `awk` will be a good start. If you have any questions during your trial, please come back again. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the great [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/), and run

```
mlr --nidx --fs "," filter '$1=~"(apple|salad)"' then head -n 1 -g 1  input.csv
```

to have

```
apple,tea,salt,fish
salad,oreo,lemon
```

- `--nidx`, to set the format, a generic index format
- `--fs ","`, to set the separator
- `filter '$1=~"(apple|salad)"'`, to apply the regex filter to the first field
- `then head -n 1 -g 1`, to take the first record, based on the value of the first field

Answer (score 1):

#### Assuming the lines are sorted

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\w+)(.+\R?)(?:\1(?2))+`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    (\w+)       # group 1, 1 or more word character, you can use ([^,\r\n]+) if the the first word contains other characters than "word" characters
    (           # start group 2
        .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
        \R?         # any kind of linebreak, optional
    )           # end group 2
    (?:         # non capture group
        \1          # backreference to group 1 (i.e. the same word)
        (?2)        # reuse the pattern of group 2, i.e. (.+\R?)
    )+          # end group, may appear 1 or more times
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: I forgot to add the non-capture repeat to my answer. Well done Toto.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ repeatedly do a regular expression replace of `^(\w+,)(.*)\R\1.*$` with `\1\2`. Have "Wrap around" selected.

Explanation:

```
^          Match beginning of line
(\w+,)     Match the leading word plus comma, save to capture group 1
(.*)       Match the rest of the line, save to capture group 2
\R         Match a line break
\1         Match the same leading word plus comma
.*         Match the rest of the line
$          Match the end of the line
```

The replace string just keeps the first line, the second line is discarded.

Demonstration:

Starting with:

```
apple,tea1,salt1,fish1
apple,tea2,salt2,fish2
apple,oranges1,ketchup1
apple,oranges2,ketchup2
apple,oranges3,ketchup3
apple,oranges4,ketchup4
salad,oreo1,lemon1
salad,oreo2,lemon2
salad,soda1,water1
salad,soda2,water2
```

Doing a "Replace all" with the above expressions yields:

```
apple,tea1,salt1,fish1
apple,oranges1,ketchup1
apple,oranges3,ketchup3
salad,oreo1,lemon1
salad,soda1,water1
```

Two more clicks on "Replace all" yield:

```
apple,tea1,salt1,fish1
salad,oreo1,lemon1
```

Each press of "Replace all" removes approximately half of the unwanted lines.